# Laptop monitor stopped working and can't be re-enabled on a Dell Latitude E6410

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, xrandr, display-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 (upgraded from 11.10), everything seemed to work fine until today when my laptop monitor suddenly stopped working.
Here are the facts:

My laptop is a Dell Latitude E6410, Intel graphics.
External Monitor is attached through a docking station.
Everything worked fine for about 6-7 month, then upgraded to 12.04
Issue started today after a week of upgrade.

I think the issue started after I ran CounterStrike 1.6, both monitors blinked and then only the attached monitor which is connected to a docking station continued to work
I thought at first that was a transient issue but then I've rebooted, removed the battery but the same happens.

Laptop Monitor and external monitor work fine up to login screen, but after I login it goes black

Whenever I try to re-enable laptop monitor from Display Manager I get errors:

```
The selected configuration for displays could not be applied 
could not set the configuration for CRTC 63
```

Not sure what technical details are required but here are some:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3120 x 1050, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1440x900       60.0 +   40.0  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
  1680x1050      60.0*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

$ tail /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[  8367.132] (WW) intel(0): flip queue failed: Device or resource busy
[  8367.132] (WW) intel(0): Page flip failed: Device or resource busy
[  8367.174] (WW) intel(0): flip queue failed: Device or resource busy
[  8367.174] (WW) intel(0): Page flip failed: Device or resource busy
[  8367.174] (WW) intel(0): flip queue failed: Device or resource busy
[  8367.174] (WW) intel(0): Page flip failed: Device or resource busy
[  8367.265] (WW) intel(0): flip queue failed: Device or resource busy
[  8367.265] (WW) intel(0): Page flip failed: Device or resource busy
[  8367.265] (WW) intel(0): flip queue failed: Device or resource busy
[  8367.265] (WW) intel(0): Page flip failed: Device or resource busy
```

I'm using gnome-shell, and the only ways I've been able to get both display working have been:

1) Booting with laptop disconnected from docking and then re attach external with VGA instead of DVI, but only worked for a session.

2) Removing xserver-xorg-video-intel, but then I gnome-shell is gone as well as dri

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Regards,

============================= WORKAROUND FOUND =============================

So I have tried few things and here is what worked:

I've installed a newer version of xserver-xorg-video-intel (2.19 vs 2.17) from ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa, it didn't work at first, it was only showing low graphics mode, so I tried with a different linux-image 3.0.0-19-generic-pae instead of 3.2.0-24-generic-pae, which I believe is 12.04 precise default, then everything started to work again, Now I've installed 3.4.0-1-generic-pae from same ppa and everything goes flawless so I believe the issue is either with linux-image 3.0.0-19-generic-pae or xserver-xorg-video-intel 2.17.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

PS: Now xrandr shows multiple modes for my laptop monitor

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3120 x 1050, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP1 connected 1440x900+1680+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 303mm x 189mm
   1440x900       60.0*+   59.9     40.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050      60.0*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Similar issue on a Dell E5510. Worked in 11.10, broken in 12.04

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!